Apply multiple summary function across columns: summarise_all: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
I am trying to create a descriptive statistics table, obtaining for each column of a data frame the following statistics: mean, sd, 10th, 50th, and 90th quantiles. I then want to transpose the dataset so that the columns are the different statistics, and each row is a variable in the dataset.
Here is a sample dataset:
dt <- data.frame(id = 1:100,
                 Numeric_Column_1 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_2 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_3 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_4 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_5 = rnorm(100))


and the code that should generate the table:

desc_table <- dt %>% select(-id)  %>%
  dplyr::summarise_all(.funs = list(mean=mean(.,na.rm=T),
                                    sd=sd(.,na.rm=T), 
                                    P10=~quantile(., c(0.1), na.rm=T),
                                    P50=~quantile(., c(0.5), na.rm=T),
                                    P90=~quantile(., c(0.9), na.rm=T)), 
                                    na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  separate(name,c("Variable", "Stat"),sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Stat", values_from = "value") %>%
  mutate(mean = round(mean, 2), sd= round(sd, 2))


However I get the following error:

Error in is.data.frame(x):
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default (., na.rm = T):
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA


How can I fix this?

First, note that scoped verbs (those that end in _if, _at or _all) have been superseded by the use of pick() or across().  See the online doc for more information.  In the absence of the output you expect based on your test input, it's difficult to give you more precise advice.  But there are many, many questions on SO that show you how to obtain the summaries you want.  Is your problem with that part of the problem or with the formatting?

Try this, modifying your code to fit the modern idiom and changing the separator in your <colname><separator><statistic> idiom from "_" to "." to avoid a clash with your column names (which might have been the source of your error)...
dt %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    across(
      -id,
      list(
        mean = \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
        sd = \(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
        P10 = \(x) quantile(x, 0.1, na.rm = TRUE), 
        P50 = \(x) quantile(x, 0.5, na.rm = TRUE), 
        P90 = \(x) quantile(x, 0.9, na.rm = TRUE)
      ),
      .names = "{.col}.{.fn}"
    ) 
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(), 
    names_sep = "\\.", 
    names_to = c("Variable", "Stat")
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Stat", values_from = "value") %>%
  mutate(mean = round(mean, 2), sd= round(sd, 2))
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  Variable          mean    sd   P10     P50   P90
  <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Numeric_Column_1 -0.04  0.94 -1.20 -0.0872  1.11
2 Numeric_Column_2 -0.15  1.03 -1.46 -0.107   1.07
3 Numeric_Column_3  0.11  1.01 -1.53  0.229   1.14
4 Numeric_Column_4  0.09  1.05 -1.17  0.103   1.53
5 Numeric_Column_5 -0.02  1.02 -1.34 -0.0238  1.38

The use of .names in the across call removes the need for your separate step.
It might be better in the long run to drop the last element of the pipe and replace it with knitr::kable(digits = 2).  This maintains the internal accuracy of your summary whilst formatting it as you request for display.
Also, see this page for an explanation of why you should use TRUE and FALSE rather than T and F.

Thanks a lot for the code and the extra hint about TRUE / FALSE. I will use them from now on!

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)
dt <- data.frame(id = 1:100,
                 Numeric_Column_1 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_2 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_3 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_4 = rnorm(100),
                 Numeric_Column_5 = rnorm(100))

my.summary <- \(x) list(mean=mean(x,na.rm=T), 
                        sd=sd(x,na.rm=T), 
                        P10=quantile(x, c(0.1), na.rm=T), 
                        P50=quantile(x, c(0.5), na.rm=T), 
                        P90=quantile(x, c(0.9), na.rm=T))

dt %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  summarise(stat = list(my.summary(value)), .by = name) %>% 
  unnest_wider(stat)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   name                mean    sd   P10      P50   P90
#>   <chr>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Numeric_Column_1  0.0904 0.913 -1.07  0.0618   1.26
#> 2 Numeric_Column_2 -0.108  0.967 -1.29 -0.226    1.06
#> 3 Numeric_Column_3  0.120  0.950 -1.03  0.0359   1.55
#> 4 Numeric_Column_4 -0.0362 1.04  -1.34 -0.00351  1.24
#> 5 Numeric_Column_5  0.106  0.989 -1.18  0.165    1.30

Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.0.2

You should use extract instead of separate for using some regex and add ~ to your functions calls inside across:
dt %>% 
  select(-id)  %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), list(mean = ~mean(., na.rm = TRUE),
                                      sd = ~sd(.,na.rm=TRUE), 
                                      P10 = ~quantile(., c(0.1), na.rm=TRUE), 
                                      P50 = ~quantile(., c(0.5), na.rm=TRUE), 
                                      P90 = ~quantile(., c(0.9), na.rm=TRUE)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  extract(name, into = c("Variable", "Stat"), regex =  "^([A-Z].*_\\d+)_(.*)")  %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Stat", values_from = "value") %>%
  mutate(mean = round(mean, 2), sd= round(sd, 2))

# A tibble: 5 × 6
  Variable          mean    sd   P10     P50   P90
  <chr>            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Numeric_Column_1  0.09  0.96 -1.17  0.0428  1.42
2 Numeric_Column_2  0.04  1.05 -1.09 -0.0829  1.42
3 Numeric_Column_3  0.09  1.05 -1.33  0.168   1.42
4 Numeric_Column_4  0     1.04 -1.29 -0.118   1.48
5 Numeric_Column_5  0.09  1.02 -1.11  0.0578  1.19

